# Testing accuracy is greater than 1 and starts off very high

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

The issue is that there are more correct samples than total samples when printed in the test loop. The train function calculates accuracy normally, but consistently starting off with 1.1-1.3 accuracy for the test function. Also, both accuracy start off very high and drop.

I am using the sst2 dataset with batch size = 16 and 55 total batches.

Here is my data preparation

```
def preprocess_function(examples):
        return tokenizer(examples["sentence"],
                         padding="max_length",
                         truncation=True,
                         max_length=MODEL_MAX_LENGTH)
    
    tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(preprocess_function, batched=True)
    tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns(["sentence",  "idx", "attention_mask"])
    tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.rename_column("label", "labels")
    tokenized_datasets.set_format("torch")

    train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].shuffle(seed=SEED)
    valid_dataset = tokenized_datasets["validation"].shuffle(seed=SEED)

    data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        mlm=True,
        mlm_probability=0.15
    )

    class_count = [sum(train_dataset['labels'] == label) for label in range(NUM_LABELS)]
    class_weights = 1. / torch.tensor(class_count, dtype=torch.float)

    class_weights_all = class_weights[train_dataset['labels']]

    weighted_sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(
        weights=class_weights_all,
        num_samples= len(class_weights_all),
        replacement=False
    )

    train_dataloader = DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        collate_fn=data_collator,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        sampler=weighted_sampler,
        pin_memory=True
    )

    valid_dataloader = DataLoader(
        valid_dataset,
        collate_fn=data_collator,
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        pin_memory=True
    )
```

And here is my training and test loops:

```
def train_loop(model,
               train_dataloader,
               optimizer,
               lr_scheduler,
               DEVICE):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    total_correct = 0
    total_samples = 0
    counter = 0
    for step, batch in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader)):
        if counter >= 100:
            break

        batch = {k: v.to(DEVICE) for k, v in batch.items()}

        outputs = model(**batch)
        logits = outputs.logits
        predictions = torch.argmax(logits[:, 8:], -1)
        # print(predictions, predictions.size(), len(predictions))

        labels = batch['labels']
        # print(labels, labels.size(), len(labels))
        correct = (predictions == labels).sum().item()
        total_correct += correct
        total_samples += labels.size(0)

        loss = outputs.loss
        total_loss += loss.detach()

        # loss.requires_grad = True
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        lr_scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        counter += 1

    accuracy = total_correct / total_samples if total_samples > 0 else 0
    return total_loss, accuracy

def test_loop(model,
              valid_dataloader,
              DEVICE):
    model.eval()
    eval_loss = 0
    total_correct = 0
    total_samples = 0
    for step, batch in enumerate(tqdm(valid_dataloader)):
        batch = {k: v.to(DEVICE) for k, v in batch.items()}

        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(**batch)

        logits = outputs.logits
        predictions = torch.argmax(logits[:, 8:], -1)

        labels = batch['labels']
        correct = (predictions == labels).sum().item() # bad line
        total_correct += correct
        total_samples += labels.size(0)
        print("Total Correct: " + str(total_correct) + " ||| Total Samples: " + str(total_samples))

        loss = outputs.loss
        eval_loss += loss.detach()

    eval_accuracy = total_correct / total_samples if total_samples > 0 else 0
    return eval_loss, eval_accuracy
```

I think I'm just not seeing something right now. Did I use the same variable for something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you know how many samples you expect to see in your validation set? This can help us verify whether `total_correct` or `total_samples` is wrong

Comment: Is your model predicting multiple labels per sample? If so, then you need to multiply `total_samples` by the number of labels per sample.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. Currently using sst2 dataset. The batch size is 16 and there are 55 batches.